# Lattice property of coprime integers

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory

I was reading on the Wikipedia page for coprime numbers that (for $a \gt b$), gcd($a,b$)$=1$ if and only if the diagonal connecting $(0,0)$ and $(a,b)$ does not cross through any lattice points inbetween. In my attempts to prove this I have tried a proof by contradiction whereby assuming gcd($a,b$) $=1$ and that the line crosses the point $(n_a,n_b)$ (with $n_a \gt n_b$, $n_a \lt a$, $n_b \lt b$) then equating the slopes: $\frac{b}{a} = \frac{n_b}{n_a}$ leads to a contradiction. But I'm coming up with nothing. I'm not even sure how I would begin to prove the other direction either. Ill take any hints you may have. Thank you.

Comment: If  $d\gt 0$ divides both, let $a=da'$, $b=db'$. The line segment passes through $(a',b')$.

Comment: Ok, this is obvious to me now.  Taking $y=\frac{b}{a}x$ to be the line and writing $a$ and $b$ in terms of prime factors, the only way to make $y$ an integer from integer $x$ is to clear the primes in the denominator.  All of which must be taken care of by $x$ since $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $\frac ba=\frac{n_b}{n_a}$, but $n_b<b$ and $n_a<a$, then the fraction $\frac ba$ wasn't completely canceled. Hence numerator and denominator share a common factor, hence they are not coprime. The argument goes in both directions, and therefore prooves coprimality if and only if $(a,b)$ is the first crossing along the line.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{b}{a}=\frac{n_b}{n_a}$ so $bn_a=an_b$ so $b$ divides $an_b$. Since $b$ is coprime to $a$ it follows that $b$ divides $n_b$, i.e. $n_b$ is a multiple of $b$. Which is kind of silly if $n_b\lt b$.